# Condition so only one of the ImageView at a time can be selected, not both at once (like dislike ImageViews)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What condition can I write so that only one `ImageView` can be selected, either one or the other. I have a **like** and **dislike** button (ImageView) that the user can hit for a post, but only one can be selected at a time and if one is selected and the user hits the other, the first one has to unselect itself. When selected in my case the ImageView changes colors.

What condition can I write so that only one or the other can be selected at a time, not both?

I have updated my code, but I am still unable to get it to work. Even with `isSelected(), setSelected()`. Could someone let me know what I am still doing incorrectly? Why isn't only one ImageView being selected. I can still select both at the same time...

**CommentAdapter**

```
public class CommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Comment> mComment;
    private String postid;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    public CommentAdapter(Context mContext, List<Comment> mComment, String postid) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mComment = mComment;
        this.postid = postid;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final Comment comment = mComment.get(position);

        holder.comment.setText(comment.getComment());
        commentLike(comment.getCommentid(), holder.commentLike);
        commentDislike(comment.getCommentid(), holder.commentDislike);
        getUserInfo(holder.image_profile, holder.username, comment.getPublisher());
        commentLikesNumber(holder.commentLikesNumber, comment.getCommentid());
        commentDislikesNumber(holder.commentDislikesNumber, comment.getCommentid());

        holder.commentLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Likes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Likes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
        });

        holder.commentDislike.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("dislike")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Dislikes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Don't be mean", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Dislikes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
        });

        holder.image_profile.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("publisherid", comment.getPublisher());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            if (comment.getPublisher().equals(mFirebaseUser.getUid())) {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Do you want to delete this comment?");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "No",
                        (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes",
                        (dialog, which) -> {
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments").child(postid).child(comment.getCommentid())
                                    .setValue(null).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Your comment has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mComment != null) {
            return mComment.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CircleImageView image_profile;
        TextView username, comment, commentLikesNumber, commentDislikesNumber;
        ImageView commentLike, commentDislike;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            commentLike = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_thumb_up_grey);
            commentDislike = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_thumb_down_grey);
            commentLikesNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_likes_number);
            commentDislikesNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_dislikes_number);
        }
    }

    private void getUserInfo(final CircleImageView prof_image, final TextView username, String publisherid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(publisherid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user != null) {
                    Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(prof_image);
                    username.setText(user.getUsername());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void commentLike(final String commentid, final ImageView imageView) {
        if (commentid != null) {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(commentid).child("Likes");
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (mFirebaseUser != null)
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_red);
                            imageView.setTag("liked");
                        } else {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_grey);
                            imageView.setTag("like");
                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void commentDislike(final String commentid, final ImageView imageView) {
        if (commentid != null) {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(commentid).child("Dislikes");
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (mFirebaseUser != null)
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_black);
                            imageView.setTag("disliked");
                        } else {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_grey);
                            imageView.setTag("dislike");
                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void commentLikesNumber(TextView commentLikesNumber, String commentid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(commentid).child("Likes");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                commentLikesNumber.setText(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void commentDislikesNumber(TextView commentDislikesNumber, String commentid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(commentid).child("Dislikes");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                commentDislikesNumber.setText(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can implement this functionality by making a selector.
in your `drawable` folder.

**image_selector.xml**

```
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/select.png" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal.png" />
</selector>
```

in your **activity.xml**

```xml
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image_selector"/>
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image_selector"/>
```

And now in your **activity.java**

```
holder.commentLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                 if(img1.isSelected()){
                    img1.setSelected(false);
                 }else(
                    img1.setSelected(true);
                    img2.setSelected(false);
                 }

    });

    holder.commentDislike.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                 if(img2.isSelected()){
                    img2.setSelected(false);
                  }else(
                    img1.setSelected(false);
                    img2.setSelected(true);
                  }
    });
```

**EDIT**

Kindly update this in your code

```
holder.commentLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Likes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Likes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        });

        holder.commentDislike.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("dislike")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Dislikes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Don't be mean", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Dislikes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
```

it should work now. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood right... So the like and dislike are changing colors just fine. What I need to implement is that you can only click on one or the other, just like for the YouTube comments. If you click like it turns blue, but if then you click dislike the like ImageView gets unselected. That's what I need. That you can only click on one or the other. Because you can't like and dislike a post. It has to be one or the other.

Comment: So for the image_selector I have to create two, one for thumbs up (like) and another for thumbs down (dislike), right? And then in my xml img1 is the thumbs up and img2 is the thumbs down, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct.  you have to create two selector i've given only example here.

Comment: It's not working properly. I can still select both ImageViews **like** and **dislike** simultaneously. Do you think it's because of the code I have at the bottom? Because of my ```commentLike``` and ```commentDislike``` methods?

Comment: this is the only way try debugging the issue. i must have forgetting someting as i write code here.

Comment: I still can't get it to work man. I uploaded the code to reflect what I have currently. Is there something I am still doing wrong?

Comment: Okay do one thing post your whole adapter class and let me have a look at this. the code which is posted above is little bit confusing

Comment: Just posted it. Let me know if you see the problem!

Comment: Do you mind if we talk in the chat? It's not working... Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211682/discussion-between-jmb-and-parth).